# Ansible : delete an item from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I have a dictionary with key values and few values are lists. I want to delete an item from the list inside the dictionary. Dict looks like below which has nested items.

**Dict Looks Like:**

```
title: Some Title
metadata : 
   manifest-version: 1.0
   key: value
installers:
   - name: someName1
     version: 1.0
   - name: someName2
     version: 2.0
   - name: someName3
     packages:
       - fileName: fileName1
         version: 1.1.1
       - fileName: fileName2
         version: 2.2.2
   - name: service
     type: install
     packages:
       - name: serviceName1
         manifest: someManifest2
         source: abcd.tgz
         files:
           - file1.tar
           - file2.tar
       - name: serviceName2
         manifest: someManifest2
         source: efgh.tgz
         files:
           - file3.tar
           - file4.tar
       - name: serviceName3
         manifest: someManifest3
         source: ijkl.tgz
         files:
           - file5.tar
           - file6.tar
```

How do I delete item which has `name: serviceName3`?
or
Can I copy the dict to another dict without the below item?

The final dict should not contain the below item:

```
- name: serviceName2
  manifest: someManifest2
  source: efgh.tgz
  files:
    - file3.tar
    - file4.tar
```

Comment: `del dict[key][key]...`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't get any option to delete item from dict but i tried to copy from one dict other with filter. Facing issue in filtering list item inside dict and appending it back.

Comment: @ArjunKanti tip to get a better experience here: the best way to respond to the kind of question asked by Ed Ward is **not** to leave a comment. Edit you question, add the code you wrote, show how you run it, explain your issue(s), show the errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution**

Let's create a list of dictionaries that shall be removed

```
  vars:
    ritem:
      - name: serviceName2
        manifest: someManifest2
        source: efgh.tgz
        files:
          - file3.tar
          - file4.tar
```

The tasks below do the job

```
    - set_fact:
        inst2: "{{ installers|selectattr('packages', 'defined')|list }}"
    - set_fact:
        inst1: "{{ installers|difference(inst2) }}"
    - set_fact:
        inst4: "{{ inst4|default(inst1) + [
                   item|combine({'packages': item.packages|difference(ritem)})] }}"
      loop: "{{ inst2 }}"
    - debug:
        var: inst4
```

give

```
    "inst4": [
        {
            "name": "someName1", 
            "version": 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "someName2", 
            "version": 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "name": "someName3", 
            "packages": [
                {
                    "fileName": "fileName1", 
                    "version": "1.1.1"
                }, 
                {
                    "fileName": "fileName2", 
                    "version": "2.2.2"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "service", 
            "packages": [
                {
                    "files": [
                        "file1.tar", 
                        "file2.tar"
                    ], 
                    "manifest": "someManifest2", 
                    "name": "serviceName1", 
                    "source": "abcd.tgz"
                }, 
                {
                    "files": [
                        "file5.tar", 
                        "file6.tar"
                    ], 
                    "manifest": "someManifest3", 
                    "name": "serviceName3", 
                    "source": "ijkl.tgz"
                }
            ], 
            "type": "install"
        }
    ]
```

**Formatting of the dictionaries**

The simple solution does not work if the dictionaries are not formatted (sorted) exactly the same way. For example, if the files' order differs, the item won't be removed

```
  vars:
    ritem:
      - name: serviceName2
        manifest: someManifest2
        source: efgh.tgz
        files:
          - file4.tar
          - file3.tar
```

This can be fixed with a couple of custom filters. Let's create the list `rhash` to simplify the comparison of the dictionaries and put it to vars

```
rhash: "{{ ritem|map('dict_flatten')|map('hash')|list }}"
```

The tasks below give the same result

```
    - set_fact:
        inst3: "{{ inst3|default([]) + [
                   filter|
                   list_select_list_bool(item.packages, negative=True)|
                   list] }}"
      vars:
        filter: "{{ item.packages|
                    map('dict_flatten')|
                    map('hash')|
                    map('bool_in', rhash)|
                    list }}"
      loop: "{{ inst2 }}"
    - set_fact:
      inst4: "{{ inst4|default(inst1) + [
                 item.0|combine({'packages': item.1})] }}"
      loop: "{{ inst2|zip(inst3)|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: inst4
```

---

**Custom filters**

```
$ cat filter_plugins/filers.py
def bool_in(x, l):
    return (x in l)

def dict_flatten(d, separator='.'):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + separator)
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in sorted(x):
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + separator)
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(d)
    return out

def list_select_list_bool(b, l, negative=False):
    l2=[]
    for bi,li in zip(b,l):
        if negative:
            if not bi:
                l2.append(li)
        else:
            if bi:
                l2.append(li)
    return l2

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'bool_in': bool_in,
            'dict_flatten': dict_flatten,
            'list_select_list_bool': list_select_list_bool
            }
```